# How to redirect users to new url on same site with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I recently changed URLs of my site.

Old URL: `mysite.com/top/1`

New URL: `mysite.com/top/page=1`

When the users visit old url I want to redirect them to new url. How can I do it with .htaccess?

i have this rewrite rule for new url

```
RewriteRule ([top,new]+)/page=([0-9]+) index.php?h=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: are you sure about the new URL? did you mean `mysite.com/top/?page=1` (question mark before `page`)?

Comment: no i updated the question check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^top/([0-9]+)$ top/page=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @Virendra your rewriterule will cause infinite rewrites :)

Comment: i already have this rewrite rule for new url 
`RewriteRule ([top,new]+)/page=([0-9]+) index.php?h=$1&page=$2 [L]`

Comment: Yes, it would cause an infinite rewrites. Let me try something else.

Comment: @RishikaSinghania You should update the question as to what you want.

Comment: I have updated the solution to work as per your request in the question, i.e. redirect `mysite.com/top/1` to `mysite.com/top/page=1`. However, are you sure you want it to be redirected in that way and not something like `mysite.com/top/?page=1`

Answer (score 0):

For your original question, you should try something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^top/([0-9]+)$ top/page=$1
```

But according to your comment on Virendra's post, this will probably better suite your needs:

```
RewriteRule ^(top|new)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?h=$1&page=$2 [R=301,L]
```

This will match both top and new, and rewrite only if a valid page number is specified.

Hope this helps

Comment: This won't redirect to `mysite.com/top/page=1` as required in the question.

Comment: According to his comment on your answer, he wants this behaviour instead of the one he is proposing in his question, but I will edit my answer to include both solutions

Comment: @RishikaSinghania which one did you try?

Comment: The internal server error is because there is a space in the flags. Change it to `[R=301,L]`

Comment: it says "page is not redirecting properly"

Comment: @UlrichPalha thank you for suggestion. I have edited my answer to reflect it